# How to convert RGBA to filter for older IE browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have the following CSS code which sets the background to a color with an opacity:

```
    #second-menu-navi a {
        float:left;
        width:125px;
        height:40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-size:11px;
        color:#ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: rgb(1, 55, 97);
        background: rgba(1, 55, 97, .85); /*#013761; /*url('theImages/nav_menu_85_b.png') repeat; /*#013761;*/
        margin:0 3px 0 0 !important;
        /*background-image: none !important;*/
        padding:0 !important;

        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px; 
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; 
        -khtml-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; 
        border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;

        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px; 
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px; 
        -khtml-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px; 
        border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;

        outline:none;

        filter:filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=85);
        /* For IE 8*/
        -ms-filter: "filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=85);";
    }
#tab-1:active, #tab-1:hover {
    background-color: #155E9B;
}
#tab-2:active, #tab-2:hover {
    background-color: #159B77;
}
#tab-3:active, #tab-3:hover {
    background-color: #1E9B15;
}
#tab-4:active, #tab-4:hover {
    background-color: #356101;
}
#tab-5:active, #tab-5:hover {
    background-color: #9B2B15;
}
#tab-6:active, #tab-6:hover {
    background-color: #9B1574;
}
#tab-7:active, #tab-7:hover {
    background-color: #70159B;
}
#break-line-2 {
    width:100%;
    height:7px;
    border-top:1px solid #02233C;
    background-color:#013761;
    position: fixed;
    top: 62px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="second-menu-navi" class="navi">
            <a href="" id="tab-1">Why Choose Us</a>
            <a href="" id="tab-2">Physicians</a>
            <a href="" id="tab-3">Medical Specialties</a>
            <a href="" id="tab-4">Locations</a>
            <a href="" id="tab-5">Urgent Care</a>
            <a href="" id="tab-6">Radiology</a>
            <a href="" id="tab-7">Lab</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

It works great in FF/Chrome/IE>=10.

How do I edit the filter codes to ensure it displays the same thing in IE that doesn't support `rgba()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google search gives me this site, which has a simple converter.  Input your RGBA code, it outputs the filter for you...

http://kimili.com/journal/rgba-hsla-css-generator-for-internet-explorer/

With the converter this:  `rgba(1, 55, 97, .85)`

Becomes this...

```
{
background: transparent;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#D8013761,endColorstr=#D8013761)"; /* IE8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#D8013761,endColorstr=#D8013761);   /* IE6 & 7 */
      zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: The only issue that comes across now is when the solid background color is used on hover it's also using the same opacity. When the user hovers over each menu tab I want the opacity to disappear and show the solid color.

Comment: @SiKni8 - I'm not sure I understand what exactly you want in terms of appearance.  What is the desired effect you want to achieve?

If you want the element to have a BG color with slight opacity, then on hover the element gains all opacity back and is solid again, then that should be as simple as changing all opacity's to 1 with a new :hover selector.

Comment: I used the same codes in each hover and just removed the `XX` from the `#XXHEXVALUE` and the solid color shows up when hovered. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the `-ms-filter` line first before the `filter`, otherwise it will not work for IE8. See **[this blog post](http://lea.verou.me/2009/02/bulletproof-cross-browser-rgba-backgrounds/)** for some information about it and **[this CSSTricks comment](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/#comment-61395)**.

Comment: makes sense. thanks.
The only issue that comes across now is when the solid background color is used on hover it's also using the same opacity. When the user hovers over each menu tab I want the opacity to disappear and show the solid color.

Comment: @SiKni8 [This SO answer might help there.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10520315/2756409)